# functions undefined

Tags: c, database

I am working in a C project. I need to retrieve data from a simple access database. I use the instructions provided in this link

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff965871(v=office.14).aspx#DataProgrammingWithAccess2010_DirectODBCExample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff965871%28v=office.14%29.aspx#DataProgrammingWithAccess2010_DirectODBCExample)

I used a Direct ODBC to connect to database because I am using ANSI C. I used the given code as a function in my project and I called it inside the main function. also I included the (sqlext.h) in the main. I have got 17 errors considering the declaration of some functions.

for example:

1- the code line:

```
rc = SQLAllocEnv(&hEnv);
```

I got the error message:

```
error: undefined reference to 'SQLAllocEnv@4'
```

2- the code line:

```
rc = SQLAllocConnect(hEnv, &hDbc);
```

I got the error message:

```
error: undefined reference to 'SQLAllocConnect@8'
```

and so on. am I missing another library or anything else? considering that my OS is windows 7 64 bit and I use microsoft access 2010 as well as Code::Blocks

Answer (score 0):

These are [windows types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  you must `#include <windows.h>` at the top of your source to use them.

This is assuming you are using windows, of course.  If not you'll have to use the correct c counterpart:

- `unsigned long` instead of `ULONG`
- `unsigned short` instead of `USHORT`

I don't see any reason to add additional levels of type alias confusion to an already unnecessary set of `typedefs` so unless you have a good reason, I recommend just using the windows types directly.

Comment: I used the #include <windows.h> and I have got another series of errors (27 errors) like: unknown type name 'SIZEL'

Comment: `SIZEL` appears to be part of [a visual C++ library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.ole.interop.sizel.aspx)  If you're just programming in C, it's out of your control.  You should probably use `size_t` or the windows type `SIZE_T`

Comment: @user3619096 I don't see any mention of `SIZEL` anywhere in that link you posted in your question.  Perhaps you should post the full `main`

Comment: the SIZEL error just appeared after adding the #include <windows.h>. it is used inside another header called <wingdi.h>

Comment: @user3619096 I don't know why that would happen.  You could try adding `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` to the top of your source, before all of the `#include`s.  I haven't done low levels windows programming in a while though so this is nearing where my windows knowledge runs out

Comment: my windows is 64 bit. anything I need to change?

Comment: @user3619096 nothing I can think of

Answer (score 0):

You need to link `odbc32.lib` into your application.

Comment: any idea about how to do that? I am completely new to database.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna add the header files like `<sql.h>, <sqltypes.h>, <sqlext.h> and <windows.h>`. You also need to put the code inside a `main()` function.